# Stackdriver monitoring - exclude specific time range in metric

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to create a policy to check whether new data is published or not for X minutes. The issue I'm facing is, that we don't get any data in the night. Therefore it's necessary to exclude a specific time range in the metric otherwise we're getting an alert every night.

Is there any way to exclude a specific time range e.g. 9 PM until 9 AM in the policy/metric?

Answer (score 1):

Alert Policy management currently does not include scheduling... but I'm thinking that using [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/quickstart), you may be able to achieve the results you are looking for, you may give this a try.

I also found that there's a [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/137839988) about Enable alerts only on certain hours. It is mentioned that a Feature Request was created, any update on this request will be published in the Public Issue Tracker or you can check the Feature Request directly as well.

You can use any gmail account to access the Public Issue Tracker.

Comment: If the information was helpful please don't forget to up vote or accept the answer