# Does GCP alerting have a time window option?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, gcp-alerts

I've got alerts for various things scheduled on my GCP services, however, I want to exclude time windows.

Is there actually a way to do so?

[image]
[image]

I've looked under both the metrics section, and under the trigger section, and have been unable to find anything. I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation either, but that could just be me not looking in the right locations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

tan,

The alignment period is a look-back interval from a particular point in time; the aligner is the function that combines the points into the look-back interval into an aligned value. Here is the Google documentation for [alignment duration](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/concepts-indepth#alignment-period).

Comment: I know how the alignment works, but I'm looking to specify periods of time where the alerts do not run. Are you saying that there's a way to configure that using the alignment?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, your concern is excluding a specific time frame where you are not receiving any data to avoid receiving alerts from the specific time frame? There is a post with the same concern here in Stackoverflow and raised an ongoing feature request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64244634/stackdriver-monitoring-exclude-specific-time-range-in-metric

Comment: Ya that post is asking about what I want. thank you!